# notify viewmodel2 if viewmodel1 property changes

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I have a scenario  in wpf +mvvm i.e if my particular property changes in viewmodel1 then  i wan to notify viewmodel2 having observable collection that property "A" has bee changed
1)I want to fire it for particular property not for all.

i have tried below code but not working .please let me know how cam i do this.

```
public class Model1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    // Create custom event
    public event EventHandler NotifyChange;

    private string testProperty;
    public string TestProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return testProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            testProperty = value;
            // If changing properties, fire your OnPropertyChanged to update UI
            OnPropertyChanged("TestProperty");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            // Fire your custom event if a property changed
            NotifyChange(this, null);
        }
    }
}


public class Model2 : INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public Model2()
    {
        // Assuming there is an accessible instance of model1
        Model1 m1Instance = new Model1();
        // Hook up your NotifyChange event from model1
        m1Instance.NotifyChange += Model1Changed;
    }

    private void Model1Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this will be triggered on change in model1
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(object singleObject)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset, singleObject));
    }
}
```

Comment: So, are you saying that when you set property TestProperty on Model1 that the event handler in Model2 is not invoked?

Comment: @TimothyGhanem what exactly i am trying to do is that when my property changes in viwmodel1 i want to rebind my observable collection in viewmodel2.....

Comment: Why don't you make Model2 inherit from ObservableCollection and then bind it to the UI from Model1?

Comment: @stylishCoder : Ensure both VM's implement INotifyPropertyChanged. subscribe to the PropertyChanged event of other view model instance. That is all you need to do to identify the property change.

Comment: May I suggest that you look into an some sort of event aggregator for PubSub events? If you are going to be following proper MVVM practices, this would be the way to go. I suggest to use Prism, if you can. Here's some more information: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5ffb84/prism-event-aggregator-in-wpf-with-mvvm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use PubSub Events

My suggestion would be to look into `PubSub` events.

My recommendation of doing this, is to use Prism. Here's some more information: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5ffb84/prism-event-aggregator-in-wpf-with-mvvm/

You will be sticking to proper MVVM practices in this case.

Here's MSDN's ever-useful guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649664.aspx

Have a really good read-up on how this works, and how to use/implement it.

---

### Alternatively

This will work, but I would still defer to using PubSub events if possible.

You could try this:

```
public class Model1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _property;
    public string Property
    {
        get { return _property; }
        set
        {
            _property = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Property");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class Model2
{
    public Model2()
    {
        // You might be storing your Model1 as a property in the Model2?
        // I don't know, but I've put it in the constructor just for example.
        var model1 = new Model1();
        model1.PropertyChanged += OnModel1PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void OnModel1PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Property")
        {
            // Do stuff here when the right property has changed in model 1
        }
    }
}
```

I have only `new`'d up a `Model1` in the constructor of `Model2` as an example - you might be assigning it and storing as a field or property elsewhere in the `Model2` ViewModel.

This might be particularly useful if you have ViewModels within ViewModels (parent VM > child VMs).

I use parent > child VMs quite regularly, and *I don't think* it's against MVVM best practices, *but I **still** use the `EventAggregator`, instead of `event`s*.

---

As a side note, if you are using C#6:

- Use `nameof(Property)` instead of "magic strings" (e.g. `"Property"`). This makes for much easier refactoring and compiler can tell you about errors - but essentially does the same job. Use this in the `OnPropertyChanged()` call in your `set`ter
- You can also use the `nameof` keyword when checking the property name, with the same principle as above. Like this: `if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Model1.Property)) ...`
- Use null propagation: `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));`. Changes the method body of your `OnPropertyChanged` to a nice one-liner, whilst still doing the same job

---

#### I digress

I would **always** look at sticking to proper MVVM practices, where possible.

I use Prism's `EventAggregator` on a daily basis and will swear by it.

Have a good read up on **PubSub Events** (you can use any type of event aggregator, but I would say to use Prism's, preferably)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: i am facing one issue when i am trying to notify tab 2 when i click on any button in tab1..can you provide any solution  for that?

Comment: *Any* button? Are you using `ICommand`s (or `DelegateCommand`s if you're using Prism's) to handle your button clicks, or are you using `btn1.Click += ...` delegate handlers?

Comment: i am using delegatecommand andwhen this is fired i  want to call  tab2 viewmodel.....which i am unable to call..please let me know how can i call tab2 method here???

Comment: Same principal as with a PubSub event. In your handler for the command, you will need to publish an event with your event aggregator. In the tab2 VM, you would need to make sure that you subscribe to that event when the ViewModel is loaded/initialized/other, and create a handler for when it receives the event from the event aggregator.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not registering to `PropertyChanged`. You're registering your event handler on `NotifyChange` so that `PropertyChanged` in `Model1` is `NULL` and so `NotifyChange` is not fired.

So, you need to implement your `OnPropertyChanged` as the following:

```
private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));

    if (NotifyChange != null)
        NotifyChange(this, null);
}
```

Finally, if you want your `NotifyChange` to be fired for a specific property, then adjust the code above to check for the `propName` before you fire the event.

Comment: can you edit above code so that i can better understand that ?

Comment: @Timothy, can I suggest that you invoke events a little better. There is always a chance that by the time you've got inside the `null` check  that `PropertyChanged` might actually become `null`. Like so: `var handler = PropertyChanged; if (handler != null) { handler(this, new ...); }`. Better still, easier to use null propogation in C#6: `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new ...);`

Answer (score 0):

If this is just to notify Model2 I think you dont need all these implementations. You can do something like

```
public string TestProperty
{
    get
    {
        return testProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        testProperty = value;
        // If changing properties, fire your OnPropertyChanged to update UI
        OnPropertyChanged("TestProperty");
        //Here you can call a method of Model2 sating that its changed
          Model2 m2Instance = new Model2();
          m2Instance.ValueChanged();

    }
}
```

Add the method ValueChanged in you model 2.

Comment: but problem comes  we are hardcoding for one property only,isn't it?

Comment: You mentioned in you question like when you change your particular property. so i thought like your requirement is like that only.

Comment: ok np @Joseph what exactly i am trying to do is that when my property changes in viwmodel1 i want to rebind my observable collection in viewmodel2